# Passing properties to ANT build.xml file

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Azure.

I want several repositories in one project. Many of the repositories will have source code which changes frequently (repoX), and one with large jar files that change rarely (repo2). Repo2 will be used for ANT builds in different repoX's. In Azure Pipeline for repoX, I want to pass repo2's path to build.xml's classpath, and can't seem to find the right syntax. I'm familiar with ANT, just need the syntax. The Azure help shows several ways to set build properties, like variables, env, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is to use [multi repo checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: devops
      type: github
      name: kmadof/devops-templates
      endpoint: kmadof

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: devops
- script: |
    echo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    ls $(Build.SourcesDirectory) *
```

Here we checkout two repos, one will go to `devops-manual` folder (self repo, in your case it should be repoX), and the other to `devops-templates` folder (repo2 in your case).

Now you should assign path to repo2 in variable. For that yous should use logging command:

```yaml
- powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=repoxpath;]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/devops-templates"
```

Now we should update `build.xml` with path and thus I recommend to use [`Replace Token` task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

```yaml
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '<path-t-your-build.xml-file>'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: false
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: true
```

In place where you want to put path you should have this token `#{repoxpath}#`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help. I was able to pass the parameter to my build file. I couldn't get the replace token task to work (I think it's deprecated), but since ANT properties are immutable, when I set my classpath variable in the ANT task OPTIONS it was picked up in the build file. Here's my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: THE_JDK
    type: git
    name: FOLDER/THE_JDK

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: THE_JDK
- script: |
    echo $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    ls $(Build.SourcesDirectory) *
    
- powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=jdk.home;]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/THE_JDK"    

- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    buildFile: 'trunk/TheApp/build/build.xml'
    options: -Djdk.home=$(jdk.home)
    targets: 'dist-trunk'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
```