# Replacetockens@3 tasks for .java file in yaml

Tags: java, bash, azure, azure-devops

I am using maven project with Java for test execution through azure Release pipelines. For security purposes I cannot pass username and password directly to the code. I am allowed to use azure keyvault and variable groups. Can I use task replacetokens@3 to replace my variables in java file with variable groups?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63807894/2777988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use task replacetokens@3 to replace my variables in java file with variable groups?

Yes. You can use the replace token task to replace the variable in Java file with variable Groups or Azure Key Vault.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Set the target replace variable in .java file with the format `#{var}#`.

For example:

```
public class  SampleApplication {

    @Parameter(names = "--count", description = #{test}#)
    private int randomNumbersCount = 1000000;

}
```

Step2: Use the replace token task in Pipeline.

```
steps:
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/*.java'
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: 'file directory'
    targetFiles: '**/*.java'
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
```

You could add the variable group in pipeline or use Azure Key Vault task to download the Azure key vault before the replacetokens task.

Then the variable in Java file will be replaced.

Comment: this task only works in release pipeline but not in build pipeline but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the yaml syntax for Replacetokens@3

```yaml
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/*.config
      **/*.json => outputs/*.json
```

For Further information check the [Replacetockens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).